# Unable to edit videos recorded in default mode on iPhone 13 mini on iPad 2020 8th generation - iOS v15.5

Tags: iphone, ipados, apple-photos

I am using default apple photo & video & camera apps on both devices. Devices run ipadOS 15.5 and iOS 15.5.

Video is recorded in "normal" video mode on iphone 13. After syncing the video to icloud and trying to edit the video in photos app on ipad 2020 i get the error message:

"Unable to edit video" This video cannot be edited because it is unsupported.

The official apple forum leaves this question unanswered for 6 months (pic 1) with several people reporting the same problem.

Is there a way how to enable editing of iphone 13 default video format using the ipad 2020 photos app? if not, what is the work around?

[image: Picture one from support.apple.com]

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use iMovie app for ipadOS. The videos are fully editable using the iMovie app.